# AWS CodeDeploy: Using multiple git repositories, or submodule inside a git repo?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, github, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I have a use case where I would want to keep two git repositories, or two applications (frontend, backend) developed by separate teams, on the same Auto-Scaling EC2 instance group.

I want to use CodeDeploy to control the deployment and revisions of the latest code.

I tried creating git submodules, but the GitHub API that CodeDeploy uses does not fetch the submodules in the tarball, so it is of limited use unless I keep a SSH key to fetch from the servers (I don't want to do that)

Is there some way I can keep the code in different repositories and utilize CodeDeploy?

Comment: How did you solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you declaring the backend as a dependency service for your frontend? If yes, is it possible to create two separate applications on CodeDeploy for now? Every time backend service is deployed first for application1 and deployment1 on CodeDeploy, and frontend service is deployed later for application2 and deployment2. Will this be a possible workaround?

Supporting for Github submodules definitely is a valid feature request.